# name() function in php, laravel, blade ?? I don't what it does...

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, atom-editor

```
Route::get('smartphones/entry', 'EntryController@s_entry')->name('s_entry')->middleware('only_admin_entry');
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/INhdi.jpg

Can anyone tell me what is the name() function doing ?

I am working on a laravel project ...and the above snippet is from the `/routes/web.php` file

Comment: You can always refer to `Laravel.com` website to read the docs. You can even search in it. I believe searching a solution there for these kind of question, will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name()` function is used to name a route, so rather than calling a route like `/abc/xyx/123` if you have named the route, you simply use the `route()` helper function  as follows

`route('route_name');`

an example would be redirection, suppose you want to redirect to some route very often, like `path/to/xyz/abc/login`. you can simply name the route as `login`. so in future even if you change the route location to `path/to/login`, other logic need not to change if you have named the route like above said.

An example is nice i think

```
//this is the route
Route::get('path/to/login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
```

you can simply refer this route by `route('login')`, like you can do the redirection

```
return redirect()->route('login')
```

I hope you are clear

Answer (score 0):

> Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes. You may specify a name for a route by chaining the name method onto the route definition

You an read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes)

> The purpose of the route name is to provide a way to refer to the route in your code. So instead of using `url('foo');` you can use `route('route_name');`. One of the advantages to this is that if you want to change the URI from `foo` to account, you need only update the route definition, not all the references to it.

```
Route::get('foo', 'FooController@method')->name('route_name');
```

Is equal to

```
Route::get('foo', ['uses' => 'FooController@method', 'as' => 'route_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes),

> Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for
>   specific routes. You may specify a name for a route by chaining the
>   name method onto the route definition:

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    //
})->name('profile');
```

You can specify a route in a view or controller by it's name like `route('profile')`.

**Advantage:**

- Suppose you have used just the route URL in 15 different views and you now need to change the route URL!! that's a lot of work. Instead had you used route names your route, URL could change at any time given the route name remains constant!

Answer (score 0):

The name() function is simply used to define the name of a route, so rather than calling a route like /xxx/abc if you have named the route, you simply use the route() helper function as follows

Route::get('path/to/signup', 'UserController@store')->name('user_signup');

you can simply use return redirect()->route('user_signup') to calling the signup form